# Why my button doesn't return "POST" django?

Tags: django, post

When I click the button I always get the method GET instead of post: Any Ideas? Thanks!

```
<body>
<form action="/reset" type="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Random Word (attempt # {{request.session.counter}})</h3>
    <div>
        <h1>{{request.session.rword}}</h1>
    </div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="">
    <button type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
<form action="/reset" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Random Word (attempt # {{request.session.counter}})</h3>
    <div>
        <h1>{{request.session.rword}}</h1>
    </div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="">
    <button type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the request is specified with the [**`method="…`** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method), so:

```
<form action="/reset" method="POST">
     …
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

due to the fact that you have used the `type` attribute, rather than the `method` attribute(which is the correct one), your code is not working. In order to change this, you must change the `type` to `method`. Also, for the action section of your form, I think it is better to use the Django url patterns, for example, `{% url 'reset' %}` rather than writing `/reset`.

```html
<body>
<!-- So in this line, I changed the action, as well as the type to method, make sure to put the actual url pattern of the /reset page rather than what I put -->
<form action="{% url 'reset' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Random Word (attempt # {{request.session.counter}})</h3>
    <div>
        <h1>{{request.session.rword}}</h1>
    </div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="">
    <button type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
<body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your answer, love the comments to help clarify the code.